# Can't use sas token+abfs in databricks to access azure storage, but it works with sas token + wasb

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-blob-storage, databricks

Background:
On the project I'm working on now, we have stg and prod databricks workspaces.
In stg databricks workspaces, there is one databricks job that needs to access some JSON files in prod azure blob storage for some data pipeline operations and the output of the pipeline needs to be written to stg azure blob storage.
Therefore, I tried to generate two SAS tokens for blob authentication. One for the stg blob and another for the prod blob. Both Azure storages we are using are ADLS Gen2

Issue:
I refer to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/connect/storage/azure-storage) here for setting my sas credentials. The problem is I have 403 issue when trying to read json`(spark.read.json("abfss://<container>@<account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<blob_path>"))` in prod blob with abfs + sas in stg databricks but it works in wasb + sas and I used the same config code to test in prod databricks which both wasb and abfs work fine.

I think my sas token and config shall be good since both abfs and wasb driver work in prod and it works in stg with wasb but this makes me, why abfs does not work in stg. I know Prod Blob has some firewall settings but since I as a dev could not access our prod Azure portal, so I don't know the details.

wondering if was could ignore the firewall setting or something. I've seen some posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71238035/reading-from-adls-from-a-synapse-notebook-with-account-key-authentification-and) which seems to have a similar issue but we do not use Synapse or trying to mount blob in data bricks just want to read the JSON in blob.

Any comments and suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to whitelist the existing IP addresses of your STG Databricks workspace in your **ADLS Gen 2** firewall settings.

[image]

Alternatively,

You can deploy your workspace with your own V-Net and then add the public subnet in the storage account firewall.

Additionally, you need permission in either way, so connect with the production environment team to enable permission for your workspace.

If you already have permission, simply add the existing workers' V-Net as shown in the above screenshot.

Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77837394/cant-use-sas-tokenabfs-in-databricks-to-access-azure-storage-but-it-works-wit) solution for more information.